# Create and read temporary file with Bazel

Tags: bazel, custom-build

I am trying to setup my custom build system for TensorFlow using Bazel.
I need to create a temporary file during the configure step that I will use as a cache during the building step.
I was able to create it in my .bzl file with:

```
repository_ctx.file(filename)
```

And after a configure I can see that it inside the folder:

```
$HOME/.cache/bazel/_bazel_$USERNAME/%MD5%/external/%repository_name%
```

where repository_name is actually `repository_ctx.name`

But I can't access to this path from my .tpl script during build time. I wanted to send it from the .bzl script via the substitutions of `repository_ctx.template` but even here I haven't found how to find this path!

It doesn't look like I can access this folder using the symbolic links like bazel-out or bazel-genfiles (which sounds very promising but is not...). I also wasn't able to create the file outside of this folder.

It's a very simple problem and I just cannot believe that there is no other way than to hardcode the path or to `find` it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess the problem is that you're not exposing the file in the repo's BUILD file for your build to use it. You need to do something like:

```
repository_ctx.file('whatever')
repository_ctx.file('BUILD', 'exports_files(["whatever"])')
```

Then you can use `@repository_name//:whatever` in any other BUILD file.

[exports_files](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/functions.html#exports_files) is used to let packages depend on source files from other packages.

Then, in your .bzl file you're loading during build time, add the file as an attribute, e.g.,

```
attrs = {
    '_my_external_src' : attr.label(
        default = Label('@my_repository//:whatever'),
        allow_single_file = True,
    ),
},
```

Then, in the rule implementation, you can access it through the context:

```
def _impl(ctx):
    print(ctx.file._my_external_src.path)
```

`.path` gets the file's path.

Comment: Hum I see. So then I have to find a way to send this `@repository_name//:whatever` from the BUILD file to the tpl file. I guess I an accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Added how to access it from your .bzl file.